# How to choose between AM230x and DHT22 temperature and humidity sensors?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, sensors, temperature-sensor

I'm looking forward to getting an accurate humidity and temperature sensor.

Right when I decided to go with a DHT22 module, I saw AM230x (AM2301, for example).

- How do I choose between DHT22 and AM2301?

Comment: Also check out the AM2320 which uses I2C.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The AM2301 and the DHT22(AM2303) are similar in a number of ways, both in price, specs, ranges and power consumption. They are usually cased a bit of a differently, with the DHT22/AM2303 being packaged with four pins (only three are in use), and the AM2301 (formerly called DHT21) is packaged with three cables and a small plug inside of the case.

I would choose based on the usage, if I'm going to use the sensor on a breadboard or a socket (going for the DHT22 pinned version), or if I'm going to have it standalone (the cabled one).

Here are links to the datasheets:

https://kropochev.com/downloads/humidity/AM2301.pdf

https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/DHT22.pdf

Comment: Thank you @JeanROdegard. Could you please give information on their usage as well? Which one has easier to use libraries, more info on the web in your experience? Which one uses more energy? Etc. Thanks!

Comment: They both use the same library, accessible via the arduino.cc site, which makes them identical in the way of usage. That being said, it really seems to me that there is most information on the DHT22/AM2303 around on the web. Searching for the DHTXX series, the most information you're going to find is based on the DHT11 sensor, but I recon that's because it's half the price (its very, very slow thought). I must admit, in my opinion, I go for the DHT22 as it simply looks better. Difference in energy usage between the two, I don't have a clue, sorry to say.

Answer (score 0):

The AM2302 has a built-in pull-up resistor, whereas the DHT22 does not. Apart of that and de different housing they should be technically identical.